# Osx terminal poweron schedule

Tags: terminal, osx

I would like to try and get my Mac (OS X 10.12.6) to set a poweron time in terminal, 1 minute from running the code.

So far I can get a specific time by inputting

```
date -v+1M
```

And I can get a specific power time by inputting

```
sudo pmset schedule poweron "mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:SS"
```

But I would like to combine them and get my Mac to run

```
sudo pmset schedule poweron "date -v+1M"
```

And then run `sudo shut down now`.

Effectively telling my Mac to turn itself back on in 1 minutes time.

Help? I have been trying for days, but I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the date (in the future) *and* format it so it's compliant with `pmset`

Your command should be:

```
date -v+1M "+%m/%d/%Y %T"
```